# Adding string to IEnumerable of type string using LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of objects, that have a property of type `IEnumerable<string>`

**My code**

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    string term = SomeMethodhere();

    students.Where(x => x.Id == student.Id)
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => 
                         { 
                            x.FieldsOfStudy.ToList().Add(term); 
                         });
 }
```

I have no erros, but `FieldsOfStudy`, remain unchanged.

What am I missing?

Comment: `x.FieldsOfStudy.ToList()` creates a *new* list which you *discard* then; it should be something like `x.FieldsOfStudy.Add(term);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x.FieldsOfStudy.ToList()` produces a **new instance** of list. So you are actually adding element to new collection.

Possible workarounds (if you can set new instace of list to property `FieldsOfStudy`):

```
{ 
   var list = x.FieldsOfStudy as IList<string> ?? new List<string>(x.FieldsOfStudy);
   list.Add(term);
   x.FieldsOfStudy = list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing?

`ToList()` creates a *new* list with all elements found in `FieldOfStudy`. It does not modify the original enumeration.

In fact, there is no guarantee anything can modify the original enumeration; it is well possible `FieldsOfStudy` is actually an array (and thus no elements can be added).

**Bottom line:** You are not supposed to modify something provided as `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want `FieldsOfStudy` to be mutable, declare it typed to an interface that provides methods for modifying the list, such as [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Design philosophy:** If you declare the `FieldsOfStudy` property as `IEnumerable<T>`, you indicate that the object returned from that property might be *anything* that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. If, in calling code, you rely on casting that object to something more specific (something to which items can be added), that calling code might break when the implementation of the `FieldsOfStudy` property changes. Things may be a bit different if the `FieldsOfStudy` property can be assigned to, as calling code can then control what is stored in the property.

Answer (score 0):

Here **loop** is made for students and then each student is updated in same loop.

Possible solution and changes :
Provided Field of study is ICollection or Iist

```
students.ToList().ForEach(s=>s.FieldsOfStudy.Add(SomeMethodhere()));
```